# Filter msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps.command into seperate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

I am trying to split the `msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps.command` column into separate columns to show the following information:

- folder
- project
- dtx package

A small sample of my data is below:

```
/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\VWGroup_Packages\AudiME SSIS Continuous Load\DealerLoad_GX_FM_WW.dtsx\""
/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\VWGroup_Packages\VWG IN SSIS Continuous Load\ABC to DW - Unapproved.dtsx\""
/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\Mercedes_Packages\Mercedes Cars SSIS Continuous Load\Submissions Load.dtsx\"" 
/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\Mercedes_Packages\Mercedes Cars SSIS Continuous Load\Validations Load.dtsx\"" 
/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\AGCO_Packages\agco SSIS Continuous Load\Metis to ABC - agco UK.dtsx\""
/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\AGCO_Packages\agco SSIS Continuous Load\Metis to ABC - agco ie.dtsx\"" 
/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\VWGroup_Packages\VWG PL SSIS Continuous Load\ABC to DW - Approved.dtsx\"" 
/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\Yamaha Packages\Yamaha SSIS Packages and WareHouse_Loads\ABCtoDWLoadModifiedCnt.dtsx\""
/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\JLR\JLR SSIS Continuous Load\Submissions Load.dtsx\""
```

I have tried to use the `substring` method, however I cannot seem to get the starting and ending number of the substring.

My aim is for the following in a ssms table:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use transform your data to xml to perform a "split" on backslashes and then you can extract only the data you need with an XQuery using the `value()` xml method (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) on MS Docs).

In the following code I created a mock table called `@tmp` with your data:

```
declare @tmp table (package_path nvarchar(max))

insert into @tmp values
     ('/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\VWGroup_Packages\AudiME SSIS Continuous Load\DealerLoad_GX_FM_WW.dtsx\""')
    ,('/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\VWGroup_Packages\VWG IN SSIS Continuous Load\ABC to DW - Unapproved.dtsx\""')
    ,('/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\Mercedes_Packages\Mercedes Cars SSIS Continuous Load\Submissions Load.dtsx\""')
    ,('/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\Mercedes_Packages\Mercedes Cars SSIS Continuous Load\Validations Load.dtsx\""')
    ,('/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\AGCO_Packages\agco SSIS Continuous Load\Metis to ABC - agco UK.dtsx\""')
    ,('/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\AGCO_Packages\agco SSIS Continuous Load\Metis to ABC - agco ie.dtsx\""')
    ,('/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\VWGroup_Packages\VWG PL SSIS Continuous Load\ABC to DW - Approved.dtsx\""')
    ,('/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\Yamaha Packages\Yamaha SSIS Packages and WareHouse_Loads\ABCtoDWLoadModifiedCnt.dtsx\""')
    ,('/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\JLR\JLR SSIS Continuous Load\Submissions Load.dtsx\""')

;with splitted_packages
as (
    select 
        cast('<x>' + REPLACE(package_path, '\', '</x><x>') + '</x>' as xml) as package_frament
    from @tmp
    )
select
     package_frament.value(N'/x[4]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Folder
    ,package_frament.value(N'/x[5]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Projects
    ,package_frament.value(N'/x[6]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Package
from splitted_packages
```

This is the final result of the previous command:

[image]